Compile time map of type string name to types in C++
In C++ is it possible to generate a compile time map of stringified type names to types. I am aware types themselves can't be mapped but could we for example map to template metafunctions which expose a type?
So specifically could we for example have one varadic template metafunction which takes some initial set of types, then at compile time constructs a static map using a fold expression for example such that at runtime we could access an exposed type and use it as a template parameter to another function, something like this
TypeMapper::Map["Type1"]::type

So then at runtime if we wanted to for example execute a specific templated function we could do
MyTypeProcessor<TypeMapper::Map["Type1"]::type>();

If this is not possible due to limitations in the language I am curious as to what limitation specifically, because individually I believe the individual parts of the idea are somewhat feasible but I'm just unsure how, so if I'm missing something here any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I am still somewhat new to stuff so I could be misunderstanding some things.

What do you need this for? First of all, are you sure you want it to be compile-time? This would mean each TU would have its own map, as opposed to a one global map.

You're not trying to build some kind of reflection or serialization code are you?  Because serialization is notoriously difficult to implement, and (runtime) reflection doesn't really fit the C++ design philosphy. C++ is a language that is very compile time phase oriented. So instead of describing HOW you want to do things, can you also explain WHAT you're trying to achieve?

This syntax cannot possibly work. Map must be an expression (not a type) and so is Map["Type1"], so Map["Type1"]::type cannot be valid. But we can simplify that! Since this expression supposedly maps to Type1 at compile time, we can just replace it with Type1.

Types can never be decided by runtime values, ever. You're likely doing it wrong.

It is possible with a different syntax.
We would like string literals to be usable as non-type template parameters, but currently C++ doesn't allow this. So let's build a replacement that is as good funcvtionally, although less convenient.
  template <std::size_t N>
  struct ct_string
  {
      char value[N] = {};
      consteval ct_string(const char (&str)[N]) : value{}
      {
          for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) value[i] = str[i];
      }
  };
  
  
  template <std::size_t N>
  consteval auto make_ct_string(const char (&str)[N])
  {
      return ct_string<N>(str);
  }

Now make_ct_string("foo") returns a value that is usable as a NTTP. We can use it to tag types with strings.
  template <typename K>
  struct is_ct_string_t : public std::false_type {};
  template <std::size_t N>
  struct is_ct_string_t<ct_string<N>> : public std::true_type {};
  
  template <typename K>
  concept is_ct_string = is_ct_string_t<K>::value;
  
  template <auto cst> requires is_ct_string<decltype(cst)>
  struct tagged_with_string
  {
      static constexpr auto value = cst;
      consteval static std::string_view tag() { return cst.value; }
  };

From here we can use types like tagged_with_string<make_ct_string("foo")>.
  using tagged_abc = tagged_with_string<make_ct_string("abc")>;
  constexpr auto abc_tag = tagged_abc::tag();

You can build a map this way:
  template <auto cst> requires is_ct_string<decltype(cst)> struct Map {}
  template <auto cst> requires is_ct_string<decltype(cst)> struct Map {};
  template <> struct Map <make_ct_string("int")> { using type = int; };
  template <> struct Map <make_ct_string("double")> { using type = double; };

  using foo = Map<make_ct_string("double")>::type;
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<foo, double>);

Note, I don't know if this is what you want, because nothing whatsoever here waits for run time. But this is definitely what I want for one of my pet projects.
